# Convert PDF To Excel in java or c#

Tags: java, c#, excel, pdf

I want to convert pdf to excel but with columns as its fields. For example:
[image]

I want to convert excel to this.
[image]

I was unable to do this. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: PDF usually does not know whether what it displays are columns, paragraphs, or whatever. Usually pdf only knows that groups of glyphs are drawn at certain coordinates.

Comment: Can we do it like first convert it into excel as it is and then converting into what output we required??

Comment: What you can do depends completely on the PDF in question. Your image does remind very much of documents like [this one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezz015t3qdqo5hk/test.pdf), [this one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2R2twh52v4kR0MxTUVCc2RISkk/view), or [this one](http://164.100.180.82/Rollpdf/AC276/S24A276P001.pdf). And those documents have been provided as samples of documents where even the basic text extraction does not work properly, let alone some interpretation...

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise converting the PDF to Excel first then manipulating the data. PDFTables has an API that can be called from C# or java (https://pdftables.com/pdf-to-excel-api). You will then be able to apply a VBA macro to look for "Name:" and "Age:" strings.